# Кэшировать конкретную папку, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, кэширование

Приветствую. Система - Ubuntu 16.04. Хотелось бы знать, есть ли возможность вручную поместить в дисковый кэш конкретную папку. Размер относительно небольшой, ~250Мб, при ~7Гб свободной памяти.

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопрос в специализированном сообществе, там подскажут быстрее. http://askubuntu.com/ и http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Igor, если автор вопроса так изощрённо-хитро зашифровал слово tmpfs, то гораздо быстрее найти [ответ в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#Linux).